# How to get real CPU frequency while system running?

Tags: cpu, freebsd

Because of the Intel Turbo Boost technology, I can't trust the CPU frequency written on the chip. I want to get the real CPU frequency while system running. I searched that `cpufreq` device could help. But `dev.cpu.n.freq` turned out only support for `dev.cpu.0.freq`.

There are no other OID like `dev.cpu.1.freq` or `dev.cpu.n.freq`.

Is there any useful tool could see the CPU frequency immediately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the absence of the `dev.cpu.N.freq` sysctl for N>0, look at the BUGS section of `cpufreq(4)`:

> When multiple CPUs offer frequency control, they cannot be set to differ‐
>        ent levels and must all offer the same frequency settings.

This is why only CPU 0 is reported.

Comment: So, Is there any tool so I can observe different cpu frequency individually?

Comment: The `cpufreq` driver can only set all cores to the same frequency. So there shouldn't be different frequencies.

Comment: I see. So, no matter how many cpus I am using, I will know the frequency each cpu has?

Comment: @Deep-SeaWhale - yes.  They will all be the same.

Comment: AFAIK `dev.cpu.0.freq` reports the base frequency, not the true boosted frequency.